# Online website layout diffrent than local

Tags: html, css, alignment, cross-browser

http://www.mohrdevelopment.com

I'm currently only testing the website with 2 browsers:

Rockmelt & Chrome.

**Rockmelt problem:**

When opened in rockmelt browser, everything functions correctly except for the "About" tab. When it is pressed my header dissapears. I even tried copying the code from one of my other tabs that looked the same (but didn't have the header problem) but the problem still prevailed.

**Chrome problem:**

Initially when the website is opened in Google Chrome, the navigation bar is aligned vertically. However if you press some of the other tabs, the bar aligns horizontally like it's supposed to (even if you go back to home tab). But if you click around on the tabs fast, there's a chance that the bar aligns vertically again.

I hope someone is able to help me with this problem, since i cannot see the logic in it.

**My HTML Code for Home tab:**

```
    <html>

        <head>

            <!-- Meta information -->
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
                content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />


            <!-- Favicon -->
            <LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="favicon.ico">

            <!-- Title -->
            <title> Jonas - Development page </title>

            <!-- Stylesheet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />


        </head>

    <body>

    <!-- Header of page -->
    <div class="headerdiv">
            <h1 class="header">Mohr Development</h1>
    </div>

                    <!--Navigation bar-->
                    <ul class="navigation">
                        <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><em class="home"/>Home</a></li> <!-- Current selection -->
                        <li><a href="photos.html"><em class="photos"/>Photos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="projects.html"><em class="projects"/>Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html"><em class="about"/>About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html"><em class="contact"/>Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>


            <div class="wrap">

                <div class="content">

                    <br>My new selection

                        <form action="" method="get">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="name"><font color="white">Enter your name:</font></label>
                                    <input id="name" name="name"/>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <label for="comments"><font color="white">Your comments</font></label>
                                    <textarea id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <label for="css"><font color="white">Do you like CSS?</font></label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="css" id="css" />
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <label for=""><font color="white">Favorite Language?</font></label>
                                    <input type="radio" /> CSS
                                    <input type="radio" /> HTML
                                    <input type="radio" /> JavaScript
                                    <input type="radio" /> PHP
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </form>

            </div> <!-- Wrap end -->

                        <!-- Sidebar -->
                        <aside>
                            <h2>Sidebar</h2>
                                <ul class="sidebar">
                                    <li class="sidebarli"><a href="#">Lol1</a></li>
                                    <li class="sidebarli"><a href="#">Lol2</a></li>
                                    <li class="sidebarli"><a href="#">Lol3</a></li>
                                    <li class="sidebarli"><a href="#">Lol4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </aside>


                </div> <!-- Content end -->


    <div class="footer">

        <p>Copyright © Mohrdevelopment.com</p>

    </div> <!-- Footer end -->

    </body>

    </html>
```

**My HTML Code for About tab:**

```
    <html>

        <head>


            <!-- Meta information -->
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
                content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />


            <!-- Favicon -->
            <LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="favicon.ico">

            <!-- Title -->
            <title> Jonas - Development page </title>

            <!-- Stylesheet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />


        </head>

    <body>

    <!-- Header of page -->
    <div class="headerdiv">
            <h1 class="header">Mohr Development</h1>
    </div>

                <!-- Navigation bar -->
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li><a href="index.html"><em class="home"/><b>Home</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="photos.html"><em class="photos"/><b>Photos</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="projects.html"><em class="projects"/><b>Projects</b></a></li>
                    <li class="current"><a href="about.html"><em class="about"/><b>About</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html"><em class="contact"/><b>Contact</b></a></li>
                </ul>


    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="content">


            <form action="" method="get">

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="name"><font color="white">Enter your name:</font></label>
                                    <input id="name" name="name"/>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <label for="comments"><font color="white">Your comments</font></label>
                                    <textarea id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <label for="css"><font color="white">Do you like CSS?</font></label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="css" id="css" />
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <label for=""><font color="white">Favorite Language?</font></label>
                                    <input type="radio" /> CSS
                                    <input type="radio" /> HTML
                                    <input type="radio" /> JavaScript
                                    <input type="radio" /> PHP
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
            </form>

    </div> <!-- Wrap end -->


            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <aside>

                <h2>Sidebar</h2>
                <ul class="sidebar">
                                <li class="sidebarli"><a href="#">Lol1</a></li>
                                <li class="sidebarli"><a href="#">Lol2</a></li>
                                <li class="sidebarli"><a href="#">Lol3</a></li>
                                <li class="sidebarli"><a href="#">Lol4</a></li>
                </ul>

            </aside>

        </div> <!-- Content end -->


    <div class="footer">

        <p>Copyright © Mohrdevelopment.com</p>

    </div> <!-- Footer end -->

    </body>

    </html>
```

**My CSS Code:**

```
body {
        font-family:sans-serif;
        background: url(images/background4.png);
        margin:0px;
    }


        /********************\
        ******* Header *******
        \********************/

    .header
     {
        background: url(images/Header.png);
        text-indent:-9999px;
        width:1092px;
        height:132px;
        margin:auto;
    }

    .headerdiv{
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        background:gray;

    }


        /********************\
        *** Navigation Bar ***
        \********************/

    .navigation {
        background:black url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_background.png);
        height:40px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        padding-left:10%;
        font-size: 0; /*remove whitespace*/
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }

    .navigation li{
        display:inline-block;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size:16px;
            }

    .navigation li a{
        display:block;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        padding: 2px 10px;
    }

    .navigation li a em{
        height:32px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0 5px 6px 60px;
        font-weight:bold;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-position: 0 50%;
        font-size:16px;
    }

    .navigation li a:hover{
        color:#00CCFF;
        background: url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_hover.png) no-repeat;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding: 2px 10px;
    }

    .navigation .current a {
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background:url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_hover.png) no-repeat;
        padding: 2px 10px;
    }


    /*Navigation bar icons*/
    .navigation li a em.home, em.photos, em.projects, em.about, em.contact{
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-bottom:5px;
    }

    .navigation li a em.home {
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/home.png);

    }

    .navigation li a em.photos{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/Photo.png);
    }


    .navigation li a em.projects{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/projects.png);
    }


    .navigation li a em.about{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/about.png);
    }

    .navigation li a em.contact{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/Contact.png);
    }
    /*Navigation bar icons STOP*/



    /* Main Wrapper */
    .wrap {
          margin:auto;
          width:80%;
          background:yellow;
        }


        /********************\
        ******* Content ******
        \********************/

    .content
     {
        background:url(images/outlets.png);
        float:left;
        width:80%;
        height:auto;
        min-width:500px;
        min-height:900px;
        display:inline;
        color:white;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 50px 50px;

    }

    .content h1, p, form, label{
        color:white;
    }


        /********************\
        ******* Sidebar ******
        \********************/

    aside{
        background: url(images/egg_shell2.png);
        float:left;
        width:20%;
        height:inherit;
        min-height:900px;
        min-width:125px;
        display:inline;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 50px 50px;
    }


    aside ul {
        padding-left:1px;
        list-style:none;
    }


        /********************\
        ****** General *******
        \********************/

    ul a {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #666;
    }

    ul a:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
        color:black;
    }



    li {
        list-style:none;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }

    label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #292929;
        font-family:sans-serif;
        padding-bottom:8px;
    }

    form ul {
        padding-left:0px;
    }

    textarea {
        width:400px;
        height:220px;

    }

    #contact {
        padding-left:5px;
        font-weight:bolder;
    }

    #Andapp{
    margin-top:50px;
    }

        /********************\
        ******* Footer *******
        \********************/

    .footer{
        float:left;
        height:150px;
        width:100%;
        background-color:gray;
        margin-top:100px;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: Quickly glancing at your code I see that you have a lot of small errors. Things such as not closing the tags properly or closing tags where there shouldn't be any closing tags. A lot of browsers try to catch these errors and fix it themselves. Sometimes you get weird outputs when the browsers cant fix it\fixes it wrong.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you mean by "tab".  Each of those HTML samples has full HTML->BODY type structure. Are these used on the same overall page?  If so, that is really bad form to have duplicated HTML and BODY tags.

Comment: @Flo Can you give me an example of a "not properly closed tag" so i know what i should look for? The other ones should be easy enough to find. And Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Mike Brant I've made 5 seperate pages sharing the same CSS code, to make them look alike. Isn't that how you build up navigation on a website? Dont mind the content of each page, i'm still developing it, so there is simmilar content on  ~3 of the pages. I just figured what you meant by duplicate HTML tags.

Comment: @JonasPedersen Sorry just your terminology in calls these "tabs" rather than pages had me thinking this might be the individual HTML content of tabbed content on a single web page.

Comment: @MikeBrant Ah okay. I fixed the duplicate HTML tags now though. Didn't fix anything unfortunately :(

Comment: @JonasPedersen Sorry I must have glanced over it to quickly. Things look fine. Also you used the textarea tag in some places. That tags has two attributes rows and cols that are mandatory while using that tag.

Comment: @Flo Alright, thank you. This browser compatibility is pissing me off though. There's no logic in the problems that occur -.-

Comment: @JonasPedersen Just so you know. I have no problems with that page while I load it in Chrome. I'm under Centos but nonetheless no problems. Make sue the page you keep reloading is not actually cached and any changes you make wont reflect if that's the case. Also check out this site. http://browsershots.org/ Its great for figuring out how your website looks on all browsers.

Comment: @Flo Hmm, good to know it works for you atleast :) I'll check http://browsershots.org/ out!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="navigation">
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><em class="home"/>Home</a></li> <!-- Current selection -->
            <li><a href="photos.html"><em class="photos"/>Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html"><em class="projects"/>Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html"><em class="about"/>About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html"><em class="contact"/>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

`<em>` tags aren't closed. It's probably best to abstract away the styling into your CSS files and focus on content in the HTML.

You can run your HTML through the [W3C Validator tool](http://validator.w3.org/) to help you with these sorts of errors.